# Obtaining the general solution of $a u_x + b u_y + c u = 0$ by using the solution on the characteristic curve

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following first order linear PDE
$$a u_x + b u_y + c u = 0.$$

I have solved this PDE by changing my coordinates to $x' = ax + by $ and $y' = bx - ay$, and the general solution was $\tilde u(x', y') = f(y') \exp{-c/(a^2 + b^2) x'}$.

But then, I wanted to solve it by other means. For example, let's consider the parametrised curve $\alpha$ s.t $dx / ds = a$ & $dy / ds = b$. This gives us, 
$$\frac{du(x,y)}{ ds} = -c u(x,y),$$
and after solving this we get $x(x,y) = x(x(s_0), y(s_0)) \exp{(-c s)}.$

However this latter analysis only valid on the curve $\alpha$ whose tangent vector at any point is $(a,b)$, and we can see that, on this curve, both results agree with each other.

**Question:**
However, I found the latter solution much more intuitive, so there any way to obtain the general solution using the second result ? I mean, in the latter analysis, we found the solution of this PDE on $\alpha$, so using this information, can we generalise this solution to whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: Your curve $\alpha$  is defined up to an additive constant, since $x(s)=as+x_0$ and $y(s)=as+y_0$. Varying the initial conditions $(x_0;y_0)$ this gives you a family of lines that covers the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Ayoub Thanks for the comment; that isa good point.

Answer (score 1):

$$au_x+bu_y=-cu$$
The Charpit-Legendre system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{-cu}=ds $$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}$ :
$$bx-ay=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from : $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{du}{-cu}$ :
$$u\,e^{\frac{c}{a}x}=c_2$$
The general solution is $\quad u\,e^{\frac{c}{a}x}=F(bx-ay)\quad$ where $F$ is any function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).
$$u(x,y)=e^{-\frac{c}{a}x}F(bx-ay)$$